# Flutter How to open a different page on a specific search in searchDelegate

Tags: dart, flutter

I have got my Auto complete search working and it show the results in a list tile .
But I want it to go to different pages that i have made for each search result

Eg:  This is my list of string

```
final product=[
  "shirts",
  "Shoes",
  "jeans",
  "informals",
   "Skirts",
  "Dresses",
  "coats"


];
```

I want it to open a different page for each of them

for Now i have just directed it to a single page.

```
  @override
  Widget buildResults(BuildContext context) {
    // show result
    return Products();
  }
```

How should I do it, cuz I am just a noob in dart and flutter I am dong this watching a tutorial video but it is not explained it that very well about my problem.
any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Navigator` to go to another specific page. You can use specific route names or you can use a switch for each result.
Here you have the [flutter doc for Navigator](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics)